# Duda con los constructores

Tags: c++

Necesito crear dos constructores uno de ellos por defecto y aquí me surge la siguiente duda, ambos constructores deben tener el mismo nombre? Por ejemplo:

```
CPartido::partidoVacio()
{ 
//Valor por defecto
m_puntosLocal = 0;
m_puntosVisitant = 0;
m_nomLocal = "????";
m_nomVisitant = "????";
m_puntsTotal = 0;
}

CPartido::partido(CCadena nomLocal, CCadena nomVisitant)
{
m_nomLocal = nomLocal;
m_nomVisitant = nomVisitant;
m_puntosLocal=0;
m_puntosVisitant=0;
m_puntosTotal = 0;
}
```

Esto sería correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> comentario del OP, creo que es util para entender esta respuesta ademas de lo que menciona en la pregunta:
>
> *pregunta + ...en una actividad me piden que hagan dos constructores de los cuales uno es por defecto y uno de ellos debe llamarse partidoVacio y
>   otro partido...*

Si, pero no, esto despacito, los **constructores** llevan el mismo nombre que la clase y son diferenciados por la lista de parametros, asi cuando llamas a un ctor para crear un objeto, por la lista de parametros que le pasa sabe cual elegir *"si todo esta bien"*.

Ahora, existen situaciones en las que los parametros pueden resultar confusos para decidirse por uno u otro, es por eso que existen los *construtores con nombre* -> "Named Constructors", toma esto con pinzas porque no se si el standard los cataloga como ctor o como "llamadas estaticas, funciones estaticas, u otra cosa" que devuelve un objeto.

Ahora un ejemplo "es de un libro" pero sirve muy bien para explicar el porque existen y que quieren solucionar los "Named Constructors" y podria hacer usted uso de estos para tenerlos idetificados por nombres, aunque no sea en su caso ambiguo por la cantidad de parametros.

---

```
class Point {
public:
  Point(float x, float y);     // Rectangular coor
  Point(float r, float a);     // Polar coor

};

int main()
{
  Point p = Point(5.7, 1.2);   
}
```

Para crear un punto usted puede hacerlo por **coordenadas rectagular** o por **coordenadas polares**, en ambos casos usted necesita de dos parametros, "iguales" para generar ambos objetos pero estos son creados de diferente manera, por ejemplo atravez de **coordenadas polares**, usted emplea el radio y angulo, osea que internamente el ctor hara calculos diferentes.

Es por eso que la sobrecarga seria ambigua porque cual de ellos escoger si la lista de parametros no son diferente, esto es lo que soluciona los ctor con nombre.

```
#include <cmath>               

class Point {
public:

  static Point rectangular (float x, float y);      // Rectangular 
  static Point polar (float radius, float angle);   // Polar 

private:

  Point(float x, float y);     // Rectangular 
  float x_, y_;
};

inline Point::Point(float x, float y)
  : x_(x), y_(y) { }

inline Point Point::rectangular(float x, float y)
{ 
    return Point(x, y); 
}

inline Point Point::polar(float radius, float angle)
{
    return Point(radius*std::cos(angle), radius*std::sin(angle)); 
}
```

Ahora los metodos estaticos son llamados constructores con nombre "named constructors".

```
int main()
{
  Point point1 = Point::rectangular(5.7, 1.2);   // Pectangular
  Point point2 = Point::polar(5.7, 1.2);         // Polar
}
```

Ahora no es ambiguo, y es aqui cuando usted lo puede usar siguiendo esa logica mas o menos para crear ctor con los nombres que usted indica.

---

los cambios podrian se algo asi **pseudoode**:

```
//..
private:

      CPartido(CCadena ..., CCadena ...);     // Rectangular 

//..
inline CPartido::CPartido(CCadena ..., CCadena ...)
{ 
//Valor por defecto
m_puntosLocal = 0;
m_puntosVisitant = 0;
m_nomLocal = ...;
m_nomVisitant = ...;
m_puntsTotal = 0;
}

inline CPartido CPartido::partidoVacio()
{ 
    return CPartido("????", "????"); 
}

inline CPartido CPartido::partido(CCadena nomLocal, CCadena nomVisitant)
{
    return return CPartido(nomLocal, nomVisitant);
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
  CPartido partido1 = CPartido::partido(stack, overflow)
  CPartido partido2 = CPartido::partidoVacio()
}
```

Comment: Lo has explicado genial muchas gracias! Me ha quedado mucho mas claro, excepto el hecho de añadir static, esto es así por ser un named constructors o porque esta función es estática de por si?

Comment: @ElPatrón mas o menos entiendo tu comentario , a ver si lo puedo responder sin liarnos, una funcion static permite que se llame a esta sin tener que construir un objeto para usarla, podria simplemete en lugar de devolver un objeto imprimir un std::cout y seguiria siendo una funcion estatica, lo que sucede en esta funcion es que devuelve un objeto, me imagino que por eso entre factores de les llamarian "Named Constructors", espero que esto responda a tu comentario si no es asi dimelo. Saludos

Comment: @ElPatrón los "_named constructors_" no se entienden como constructores... lo que sucede es que internamente acaban llamando a los constructores de verdad. Son más bien una utilidad que se crea para permitir la creación de objetos complejos sin compilcar la lógica de los constructores.

Comment: @eferion gracias por comentarlo asi queda mas claro, yo intente explicarlo sin que se mezclaran las cosas, pero al leer su pregunta y su comentario diciendo que era un ejercicio me imagine que los tiros iban por  hacer uso de "Named constructors". Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría algo así

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CPartido
{
    private:
       int m_puntosLocal;
       int m_puntosVisitant;
       ....
    public:
       // Constructor with no arguments
       CPartido(): m_puntosLocal(0), m_puntosVisitant(0) { }

       // Constructor with two arguments
       CPartido(int nomLocal, int nomVisitant): m_puntosLocal(nomLocal), m_puntosVisitant(0){ }

       // Function
       int CPartidoPartido() {  return (m_puntosLocal* m_puntosVisitant);  }

...
```

Comment: Entonces un constructor por defecto debe tener el mismo nombre que al menos otro constructor por parametros? Es algo que me tiene en duda, porque en una actividad me piden que hagan dos constructores de los cuales uno es por defecto y uno de ellos debe llamarse partidoVacio y otro partido

Comment: Si es el mismo constructor con sus respectivas propiedades, si debe llamarse igual, lo que vas a hacer es hacer una sobrecarga "overloading".

Comment: o también puedes crear un método o función que puede llamarse diferente y devolver un valor u objeto, tal vez esa es tu confusión entre constructor y función.

Comment: Lo siento creo que no me estoy explicando bien, necesito hacer dos constructores llamados partidoVacio y partido el primero de ellos por defecto, pero la forma en la que lo he hecho no es la correcta

Comment: Podrías darle una mirada al tema de la Herencia en c++ para que te quede mejor; "Esta propiedad nos permite crear nuevas clases a partir de clases existentes, conservando las propiedades de la clase original y añadiendo otras nuevas."