# ¿Se puede crear un método que devuelva un valor del mismo tipo que la clase?

Tags: c++, poo

¿El siguiente código sería correcto?

```
class Persona {
   private:

   string nombre;
   bool sexo;
   int edad;

   public:

   Persona ();
   bool getSexo ();
   int getEdad ();
   Persona reproducir (string s);


}
```

Comment: Si, *pero tanto como correcto entre otras cosas abria que ver la implementacion, pero en lineas generales si* esto puede estar relacionado para que entienda una de las cosas por la que esto se permite -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55086/duda-con-los-constructores. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede crear un método que devuelva **lo que quieras**.

```
class Persona {
public:
  Persona otra( ); // Devuelve un objeto.
  Persona &ref_a_otra( ); // Devuelve una referencia.
  Persona *ptr_a_otra( ); // Devuelve un puntero.

  static Persona crear_persona( ); // Devuelve un objeto.
  static Persona &crear_ref_persona( ); // Devuelve una referencia.
  static Persona *crear_ptr_persona( ) // Devuelve un puntero.
};
```

En realidad, que una función sea *miembro* de una clase solo afecta a como se buscan los identificadores (variables y otras funciones), y, si no es estática, dicha función recibe un parámetro oculto llamado `this`, que es un puntero a la instancia.

Si la función *pertenece* a una clase, cuando en su cuerpo se hace referencia a una variable u otra función, el compilador busca comenzando por el propio cuerpo de la función, luego busca entre los componentes de la clase, y continua subiendo de *ámbito*.

Por lo demás, una función miembro puede devolver **cualquier cosa**, exactamente igual que una función *suelta* (sin pertenecer a una clase).

Comment: class Individuo
{
private:
 string nombre;
 string sexo; 
 string n_padre;
 string n_madre;
 Arbol<Individuo> a_gen;
public:
 Individuo ();
 void setNombre (string s);
 void setSexo (char sexo);
 bool getSexo ();
 Arbol<Individuo> generar_arbol_genealogico (); 
}; Entonces esto es posible hacerlo no?

Comment: Posible, es. Otra cosa es **el rendimiento** de pasar/devolver tantos objetos *por valor*. Y posibles problemas en la pila si, dentro de tus funciones, creas objetos *automáticos* (sin usar `new`).

Comment: Evalúa *seriamente* la posibilidad de usar *referncias* y/o *punteros*.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes crear un método que te devuelva un valor como el de la clase, lo que debes de hacer es que te devulva la dirección de memoria del objeto a devolver.

```
Class Persona
{
    Persona *persona nombreMetodo(string str);
}

//Método que devolverá el tipo de dato Persona
Persona* Persona::nombreMetodo(string str)
{
    //En caso de crear un nuevo objeto de tipo Persona

    Persona *objeto = new Persona();

    /* O si tienes una lista de objetos Persona realiza una busqueda y 
    cuando encuentres el objeto solo lo retornas */

    Código...

    return objeto;
}
```